# Error loading plugin manager in Grails/Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm working on a simple grails project when I encountered a problem.  I have done lot of research but I haven't found the right answer.

The thing is I have 3 domain classes namely **Inventory**, **User** and **Movement** and the relationship between them is **one-to-many** for **Inventory** and **Movement** and the same for **User** and **Movement** so **Movement** is pretty much in the middle.  I managed to connect the Inventory and Movement well but the other relationship shows an error below.

```
Error |
Error loading plugin manager: Property [movements] in class [classcom.inventory.User] is a 
bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. 
Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [user] or use the 
'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. 
Example: static mappedBy = [movements:'myprop'] (Use--stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

This are my domain classes:

Users:

```
class User {

    String userID
    String fullName
    String position
    Department department 

    String toString(){
        fullName
    }

    static hasMany = [inventories: Inventory, movements: Movement]

    static constraints = {
        userID blank: false, unique: true
        fullName blank: false
        position()
        department()
        movements nullable: true
    }
}
```

Movement:

```
class Movement {

    User oldUser
    User newUser
    Inventory inventoryID
    Date movementDate
    User userResponsible

    //static belongsTo = User

    static constraints = {
        inventoryID blank: false
        oldUser blank: false
        newUser blank: false
        movementDate()
        userResponsible blank: false
    } 
}
```

Inventory:

```
class Inventory {

    String inventoryID
    String code
    String description
    String serial_num
    Date purchase_date
    byte[] image
    Date record_date
    String remarks
    Type type 
    Brand brand 
    User user 


    static hasMany = [movements: Movement]

    String toString(){
        "$inventoryID, $type"
    }

    static constraints = {
        inventoryID blank: false, unique: true
        code blank: false
        description nullable: true, maxSize: 1000
        serial_num blank: false
        purchase_date()
        image nullable: true, maxSize: 1000000
        record_date()
        remarks nullable: true, maxSize: 1000
        type()
        brand()
        user()
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve the error..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that gorm is unable to distinguish between the newUser and the oldUser on your Movements class. Try adding a mappedBy section and adding another part to your hasMany property to your user class, below is an example that should work:

```
    class User {

    String userID
    String fullName
    String position
    Department department 

    String toString(){
        fullName
    }

    static hasMany = [inventories: Inventory, movementsByOldUser: Movement, movementsByNewUser: Movement]
    static mappedBy = [movementsByOldUser: 'oldUser', movementsByNewUser: 'newUser']
    static constraints = {
        userID blank: false, unique: true
        fullName blank: false
        position()
        department()
        movements nullable: true
    }
}
```

For some documentation reference see: http://www.grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html

Comment: your solution is worked, but the application still got an error which I solved by removing 'movements nullable: true' in the constraints of User class.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how do I extend my application so that when an inventory is being moved from olduser to newuser in the Movement class, the inventory owner should be changed and reflected in the User class.  Is it that possible and how can I go about doing it.